# Stream encountered HTTP error: 404 HTTP error response text

Tags: api, http, twitter, stream, tweepy

```
def start_streaming_tweets(self, search_term):
    self.filter(track=search_term, stall_warnings=True, languages=["en"])
```

if **name** == '**main**':
twitter_stream = TweetListener(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
twitter_stream.start_streaming_tweets(search_term)"

and  i got  this  erreur :
Stream encountered HTTP error: 404
HTTP error response text:
Stream encountered HTTP error: 404
i asked chatgpt but  he tell me thats  its  a problem wi`iei`th twitter seveur

i need help plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using Twitter v2 endpoints for streaming.
Twitter deprecated the v1.1 stream endpoint thats why you are getting this error.

Check the sample streaming code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/main/Filtered-Stream/filtered_stream.py).